# How can I identify a counterfeit Xbox 360 controller?

Tags: xbox-360, controllers

I recently bought a Wired Xbox 360 controller from Ebay, and I'm trying to figure out whether it's counterfeit.

It's two-tone black and gray, which [according to Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xbox_360_Controller#Standard_Controller_Colors) means it's probably the Elite edition of the controller.

Here's what makes me suspicous:

- There's no breakaway cable near the USB port (Microsoft's term is [Inline Cable Release](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/907634)), the cable is one piece from controller to USB port
- The cord is about 7 feet long
- The hologram sticker on the back says "Microsoft" but doesn't have the real Microsoft logo, there's no slice taken out of the "o" in "Micro"

Here's a number of details that are correct, as far as I can tell:

- The "Microsoft" logo etched on the top of the controller is correct, it has the split "o" and connected "ft"
- It seems to work correctly when plugged into my computer
- The front of the controller matches [this image](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Xbox360Controllerblack_Upview.jpg) exactly
- At the USB end of the cord, the grey wider plastic piece you're intended to pull on has the little nub on top. (You can see what I'm talking about in [this picture](http://img.diytrade.com/cdimg/922801/9338136/0/1244688035/Charge_cable_for_Xbox360_controller.jpg), the nub is to the left of and below the first "w" in the watermark)

I know pictures would probably be helpful, I'll work on taking some.

Comment: There are official Microsoft controllers with permanently attached cables.  The hologram sounds suspicious though.

Comment: I own a counterfeit mouse-pad with the same Microsoft logo you described.

Comment: Buy from Amazon. You'll usually get a good price and you'll definitely get peace of mind. I'll pay $5 more for that any day.

Comment: Good picture examples can be found on this dupe: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/89194/is-this-xbox-360-controller-fake-how-can-i-tell

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Microsoft has changed the looks of its controllers over time.

For instance, my original wireless controller from my Elite looks identical to the images you showed, and says Microsoft twice on the top of the controller (one hologram, one etched in).

My newer wireless controller, that came with the Wireless adapter for Windows, is all black, and only has the hologram on the top with Xbox 360 etched in the top.

On both controllers, the hologram is right above the battery pack, so it may be located in a different location on a wired controller.

Comment: Does the hologram on yours have the split "o"?

Comment: @daxelrod: No, it doesn't.  Each letter is close together, but slightly separated on the hologram, and the hologram also has XBOX360 (and a trademark symbol) in the background several times.