# Is this Xbox 360 controller fake? How can I tell?

Tags: xbox-360, controllers

Just bought it on ebay from a chinese seller with high rating. The item description said it was GENIUNE. But I'm still skeptical. Even thought It works well on my pc the box looks suspicious on the backside. What should I look for to verify the authenticity of this controller?

Please take a look at these photos, and use them as an example if possible.

[image: front of controller]
[image: top of controller]
[image: back of controller]
[image: bottom of controller]
[image: controller cable]
[image: back of box]
[image: front of box]
[image: instructions]

Comment: Looks pretty darn legit to me. Usually fakes don't put this much effort into making them look real

Comment: The little silver sticker on the back of the controller, the oval one? Does that say anything on it?

Comment: It has an hologram with the "Microsoft" logo on the center and the "XBOX 360" logo all around repeated as a pattern (eligible twice).

Comment: The way you can tell that balances reliability with ease is to weigh a known "legit" controller vs the one you have here.  Counterfeits tend to weigh less, as they're usually cost reduced with fewer parts populated.  I'd probably take it to a (friendly) used game shop along with a small scale.  That said, it looks pretty legit, although it's certainly not a US model.

Comment: Thanks, I will probably go to the house of my friend's friend and compare with a retail 360 controller. (I hope it's wired like this one) As far as I can tell the weight feels right, it weights noticeable more than a PS2 controller.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are quite a few ways to check if you have a genuine Microsoft product.

- The best way to tell is to check if it has a holographic Microsoft sticker on it. All genuine Microsoft products have this quality (watch [this video](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/showcase/details.aspx?uuid=e7ffbdf3-6404-4313-a065-123cd219d88b) for a demonstration of this)
- In addition, you must remember that Microsoft has changed the design of their controllers over time, and therefore the one that you have may be different from the one your friend has. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xbox_360_Controller) is helpful in identifying which controller you and your friend have.
- The logo should look like [this](http://gamerfitnation.com/2011/08/xbox-360-winning-u-s-console-market-for-seventh-months-straight/microsoft-logo/). The "Microsoft" logo on the top of the controller should have a split "o" and connected "ft"
- Check the weight of the controller with another controller you are sure is real.

Comment: It all points out that the controller is geniune. Specially thanks to this page http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/howtotell/Hardware.aspx#Xbox

Comment: After more research turns out the controller is actually fake, I ended up buying a legit controller and was able to see the differences, as Jeffrey explained in his answer. The hologram is fake, the Microsoft typography is wrong, the cable doesn't have an inline release, and the worst part is that the thumb-stick behaves like a d-pad, it doesn't have the same level of precision as the legit gamepad. So If you bought this on Ebay like me try to get a refund as soon as possible.