# New Xbox 360 controller won't turn on with official charge pack but will with batteries?

Tags: xbox-360, controllers

I have an official charge pack kit from Microsoft and I recently bought a (supposed to be) genuine Microsoft controller off of eBay (from a high rep seller), the controller looks pretty good if it's a counterfeit (has all the stickers, though they are crooked) but the thing is it won't turn on if I use the charge packs (all three of them work), it will only turn on if I use the battery pack with double A's.

Any solutions? And does this mean the controller I bought is a knock-off?

The only thing suspicious (other than the above) is the hologram is different than all the holograms on the official products I own, all of my controllers the hologram has a Microsoft in the middle and it all looks a bit blurred. This controller's hologram sticker has Microsoft and Xbox 360 in alternating rows and is clear and easy to read.

Couldn't get a good picture of the known legit hologram but this is what two of my known controllers' hologram looks like:

[image]

Unknown hologram and grey plug and play port, the mic port is also grey instead of black

[image]

I also noticed that the mic port and plug and play are grey instead of black like the known black one. Without taking apart the unknown it looks like a cg2 board.

ETA: more pictures, if that's more helpful in determining a  real vs fake.

known, 
unknown, 
known on left, 
known on left.
[image: known battery pack]
[image: unknown]
[image: known on left]
[image: known on left]

Comment: please provide screenshots of the controller you KNOW is legit, and the one that is suspect.

Comment: related http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/31760/how-can-i-identify-a-counterfeit-xbox-360-controller?rq=1

Comment: It could be that the contacts for the charge packs are corroded.  Clean with concentrated (95% or higher) rubbing alcohol.

Comment: added pictures/links to pictures

Comment: re: gray mic port. Could you just have bought an old style controller (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Xbox-360-Controller-Black.jpg), and are comparing it to a new style controller (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Xbox-360-S-Controller.png)? One way to tell is the guide button is glossy on the new style controller.

Comment: the only thing that is grey is the mic port and the plug and play port, the guide button is glossy (chrome instead of the silver/grey), everything else (triggers, left and right stick, dpad, bumpers - even the mic trim) is black. maybe its an old style board in the new colours to appear new? i'm not sure.

Comment: Perhaps the title should be edited to "Is this controller a knock-off?", since that's the bulk of the question.

Comment: You have verified the battery pack is good.  I often find if the battery pack goes uncharged for months it will be unable to hold a charage at all.

Comment: I don't know if it's a knockoff, I'm wondering that too but I want to know if the battery packs not working (as they are official and work in all my other controllers) indicates a knockoff or if there's a different issue with the controller. Eg. Maybe it's the Europe/Asia variant of a 360 controller and that's why it a) looks different (hologram) and b) won't work with my charge packs

Comment: Was just thinking that maybe the charge packs and your controller have the +- signs backwards and the battery holder that came with the controller has them correct for the controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks everyone for the help I filed a dispute and sent several messages back and forth they kept claiming it was new and a genuine product (and how could we do business and have high rep if we lied?). Finally I sent them all the pictures I had took and all the google info I found and asked them how they could claim it was a legit controller when all this stuff was different?

They finally admitted it was "original" made by a third party though, even though it was advertised (and upon messaging before buying they claimed it) as a genuine microsoft product.

**tl;dr - third party knockoff, probably why the charge packs don't work. use the pictures above of the hologram (and other details) as a guide.**